# In splunk dashboards, what is the most efficient way to apply user input changes?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am new to splunk.

I have a dashboard with multiple dropdown inputs.  Let's say:

- Input 1
- Input 2
- Input 3

When the user chooses Input 1 I want to populated the dropdowns for Input 2.
When the user chooses the value for Input 2 I want to populate the dropdowns for Input 3.

When all Inputs are populated I want to populate the dashboard.

Currently I have defined all inputs with the `searchWhenChanged=true`.

But I think all the queries are ran each time one of the inputs are changed.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

When I need to do something like this, I have each successive input hidden until the previous is chosen (using the `depends="$token_name$"` in the input's [tag](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Viz/PanelreferenceforSimplifiedXML#input_.28form.29))

Inside the first input tag, then, you'd have a `<set token="display_input_2">yes</set>`

In the second, `<set token="display_input_3">yes</set>`, etc

You can keep the "search on change" active - but if all three input fields are needed to actually get data, you won't see anything until they've all been selected

You can *also* put a `depends="$last_input_token_name$"1` in the `<row>` or `<panel>` that needs to hide until everything's been selected